# Flip the color of something when you click on another thing

Tags: javascript

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhaem/0eoxh3gu/)

```
var orangeMode = true

flip = function() {
  orangeMode = !orangeMode;
}
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click", flip);

if (orangeMode) { 
  document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
```

Manually changing the variable from true to false on the first line flips the color of the circle from orange to blue, but tapping the box in the corner is meant to flip between them, but doesn't work. Feel like there is something basic I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your function changes orangemode and exits.  The if statement is not executed again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[check the orange value in flip method itself](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/0eoxh3gu/1/)

```
var orangeMode = true

flip = function() {
  orangeMode = !orangeMode;
  if (orangeMode) { 
  document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click", flip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, moving the code to change colour inside the event handler will work, I'd suggest to use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/soukgsfw/)

Create a CSS class to set the background color to blue and toggle this class when the box is clicked.

`classList.toggle('className')` will add the class if it is not already added on the element otherwise it'll remove the class.

```js
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('circle').classList.toggle('blue');
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
#circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
#circle.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>

<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: But classList toggle method is currently not supported in IE !!

Comment: @RajanSingh It is [supported by IE10+(except second argument)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility), for those versions which do not support `classList` you can use shims provided by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#JavaScript_shim_for_other_implementations)

Answer (score 0):

You could actually check the color and get rid of the global variable:

```
var flip = function() {
  var baseColor = "orange";
  var currcolor = document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor;
  document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor = (currcolor == baseColor) ? "blue" : baseColor;
}
document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("click", flip);
```